# IIS 10 - IP Address and Domain Restrictions settings are denying all traffic

Tags: windows, security, iis, iis-10, ipv4

I have a server that has multiple sites set up on it in IIS 10.

On one of the sites, I want to allow access to a range of IP Addresses, and deny traffic to the site from all other IP Addresses.

In IIS, in the IP Address and Domain Restrictions settings, I have added an ALLOW rule for the range of IP addresses, and a DENY rule for denying all other traffic. However, all traffic to the site is being denied.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

[image: IIS 10 IP Address and Domain Restrictions Settings]

Comment: Duplicate to your own https://serverfault.com/questions/1143280/iis-10-ip-address-and-domain-restrictions-is-denying-all-traffic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong.

The IP range I was using was my network's public IP range, but I was testing out the rules on a server that's internal on our network, and so when I instead used the internal network IP addresses, the Allow rules started working.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to allow access to a specific range of IP addresses while denying access to all other IP addresses outside of the specific range. But you set the IP address to "deny 0.0.0.0" in IP Address and Domain Restrictions. Specifically, 0.0.0.0 is a special IP address that represents "all IP addresses" or "any IP addresses", so set "deny 0.0.0.0" means deny access to all IP addresses.

You just need to add "Allow" entries in the IP Address and Domain Restrictions module for the specific IP ranges you want to allow. Then in the "Edit Feature Settings…”, select "Deny" for "Access for Unspecified Clients". Please test access again after making changes to the configuration.

[image]